# Ace Editor autosize 2 editor windows on same page, one works perfect

Tags: javascript, python, editor, ace-editor

window 1 (ACE Editor) in my code (shown below) works perfectly,  exactly as intended... which is resizing depending on the size of code that has been loaded into the ACE Editor window.  I have the exact same code for window 2 and i want it to do exactly what window 1 does... but window2 doesnt work at all??? please help if you can, its for a good cause :D :) thanks so much! :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var heightUpdateFunctionWindow1 = function() {
        var newHeight1 = window1.getSession().getScreenLength() * window1.renderer.lineHeight + window1.renderer.scrollBar.getWidth();
        $('#source1').height(newHeight1.toString() + "px");
        window1.resize();
    };

    heightUpdateFunctionWindow1();
    window1.getSession().on('change', heightUpdateFunctionWindow1);

    var heightUpdateFunctionWindow2 = function() {
        var newHeight2 = window2.getSession().getScreenLength() * window2.renderer.lineHeight + window2.renderer.scrollBar.getWidth();
        $('#source2').height(newHeight2.toString() + "px");
        window2.resize();
    };

    heightUpdateFunctionWindow2();
    window2.getSession().on('change', heightUpdateFunctionWindow2);
})

var window1 = ace.edit("source1");
window1.setTheme("ace/theme/textmate");
window1.setFontSize(16);
window1.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/python");
window1.setAutoScrollEditorIntoView(false);
window1.maxLines(Infinity);

var window2 = ace.edit("source2");
window2.setTheme("ace/theme/textmate");
window2.setFontSize(16);
window2.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/python");
window2.setAutoScrollEditorIntoView(false);
window2.maxLines(Infinity);
```

Answer (score 0):

lol never mind worked it out - removed these lines and all seems working:

```
window1.setAutoScrollEditorIntoView(false);
window1.maxLines(Infinity);
```

and:

```
window2.setAutoScrollEditorIntoView(false);
window2.maxLines(Infinity);
```